# How to get a test's run execution time detail from JUnit's TestResult?

Tags: junit

I am new to JUnit, but this is what I am trying to do:

- generate data with my DataGenerator class;
- instantiate a test class MyTestClass
- pass to MyTestClass the test data generated data (first step)
- run the test
- collect TestResult result

With the above, all works, but I cannot see any **timing** information (time it took to complete the test) at the **TestResult** object. Anything being done wrong here ?

The approach above is because I need to run this on other test classes using the same data.

```
    DataGenerator testData = new DataGenerator();
    MyTestClass myTestClass = new MyTestClass("mytestmethod");
    myTestClass.setBaseLine(testData);
    try {
        TestResult testResult = myTestClass.run();
        System.out.println(testResult.wasSuccessful());
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestSupervisor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by timing information?  do you mean how long the test took to run?

Comment: yes. I am editing the question to complement that. thks

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4 has a timeout annotation that will fail the test if the test too long.

```
//this test will fail if it takes longer than 1 sec
@Test(timeout = 1000)
public void myTest(){
   ...
}
```

I think you can get around the DataGenerator issue by using a better TestFixture.

If all of your tests that use the DataGenerator are in the same test class, you can use the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations to set up and tear down data that is used across tests.  (those methods with those annotations are called only once before/after all the tests are run).